# Relation between basis and linearly independence

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

General question in linear algebra:

Let $T:V\to W$ be a linear transformation and $\{v_1\,\dots,v_n \}$ a basis for B. 
If $\{v_1\,\dots,v_k \}$ is a basis for $kerT$.

Can I conclude that the vectors $\{T(v_{k+1}), \dots , T(v_n)\}$ are linearly independent in W?

A clear explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: No, let $T$ be the zero map.

Comment: Assuming T is not the zero map?

Comment: @Randall if $T$ is the zero map then $k = n$

Comment: Still no, for the same reasons.  $T$ is allowed to collapse stuff.

Comment: Hmmm, need to re-read.

Comment: If this is not true so how is the proof of the dimension theorem valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can indeed conclude that those vectors are linearly independent.

In particular, let $c_{k+1},\dots,c_n$ be such that 
$$
c_{k+1}T(v_{k+1}) + \cdots + c_n T(v_n) = 0
$$
we can then write
$$
T(c_{k+1}v_{k+1} + \cdots + c_n v_n) = 0
$$
which is to say that $c_{k+1}v_{k+1} + \cdots + c_n v_n \in \ker T$, which is the span of $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$.
However, since the set $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ is linearly independent, the vector $c_{k+1}v_{k+1} + \cdots + c_n v_n$ can only be in the span of $\{v_1,\dots,v_k\}$ if $c_{k+1} = \cdots = c_n = 0$.

Comment: Wow thank you for this explanation. A few more questions: If the dimension of $W \lt n-k$ then how is that possible? Also, can I conclude that $\{T(v_{k+1}),…,T(v_n)\}$ is a basis for $ImT$?

Comment: It is in fact impossible to have $\dim W < n - k$.  In particular, the kernel will necessarily satisfy $\dim \ker T \geq \dim V - \dim W$.  And yes, you can indeed conclude that $\{T(v_{k+1}),\dots,T(v_n)\}$ is a basis for the image of $T$.

Comment: Nice and clear.

Comment: Thank you. Great answer!

Comment: @Randall glad you think so

Comment: @GADI you're welcome!